# Vertically centered horizontal rule filling the rest of a line?

Tags: vertical-alignment, rules

I'd like to have a horizontal line extending from the end of the text on a line to the right margin. So far I've found `\hrulefill` and `\leaders\hrule\hfill`, but these draw a line that's flush with the baseline of my text — how can I get it to be vertically centered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\begin{document}
Here is some text\xfill{1pt} \par
Here is some text\xfill{8pt} \par
Here is some text\xhrulefill{blue}{2pt}\par
Here is some text\xhrulefill{cyan}{1ex}\par
Here is some text\xrfill[0ex]{1ex}[red] \par
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Is the command `\xfill` defined in **hxfill**? It seems not.

Comment: Unfortunately, even the package documentation refers to the missing command.

Answer (score 19):

You can define a command similar to `\hrulefill`, but changing the height and depth of the rule used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent text\hrulefill

\noindent text\Vhrulefill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\filltoend{\leavevmode{\unskip
  \leaders\hrule height.5ex depth\dimexpr-.5ex+0.4pt\hfill\hbox{}%
  \parfillskip=0pt\endgraf}}
\newenvironment{filllines}
  {\par\let\par\filltoend}
  {\par}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

A paragraph outside the environment can be ended with the
command \verb|\filltoend| like this one.\filltoend

\begin{filllines}
In this environment all paragraphs will be ended with a line.

As it's shown here.
\end{filllines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of this approach with respect to the other proposed solutions is that it has no issues when the paragraph happens to end exactly at the right margin. However it won't work, for TeXnical reasons, with list environments inside `filllines` (list environments redefine `\par` in terms of the primitive commands, not taking into account its present meaning), but `\filltoend` will work.

If a rule is needed no matter what, change the specification

```
  \leaders\hrule height.5ex depth\dimexpr-.5ex+0.4pt\hfill
```

into

```
  \leaders\hrule height.5ex depth\dimexpr-.5ex+0.4pt\hskip1em plus 1fill
```

which will draw a rule at least 1em wide.

Comment: Did you opt for `\endgraf` to deal with redefinitions of `\par` within list environments?

Comment: @macmadness86 Most likely so

Answer (score 6):

The following `\centerline[<height>][<thickness>]` produces a rule at height `<height>` (default is `0.5ex`) and thickness `<thickness>` (default is `0.4pt`). The horizontal alignment is not entirely optimal compared to a traditional `\hrulefill`, but this is perhaps not an issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linegoal}% http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\centerrule}{O{0.5ex} O{0.4pt}}{%
  \leavevmode\rule[#1]{\linegoal}{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
Here is some text\centerrule \par
Here is some text\centerrule[0pt] \par
Here is some text\centerrule[0.5ex][1pt] \par
Here is some text\centerrule[0pt][2pt]
\end{document}​
```

The interface is provided by the [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), while the end-of-line estimation is done using `\linegoal` (from the [`linegoal` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal)). It requires at least 2 compiles.