# Section heading, text embedded in horizontal rule

Tags: sectioning, rules

I would like to create section headings that look like this:

```
-------------------- Some title --------------------
```

So a horizontal rule with text embedded in the middle. Should I use titlesec or fancyhdr packages for this? Does someone have an example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). The vertically centered horizontal `\hrulefill` called `\Vhrulefill` was taken from [Vertically centered horizontal rule filling the rest of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/vertically-centered-horizontal-rule-filling-the-rest-of-a-line)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{\noindent\Vhrulefill~\thesection\quad#1~\Vhrulefill}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}​
```

Specifying the package option `explicit` allows you to have more control over the placement of the sectioning title via the `#1` parameter in `\titleformat`. Of course, in this sense, you can also add a different space between the section and the horizontal rules (I've used `~` in my example). However, this modification (as well as the sectional formatting) may all be up to personal preference. I've also used `\bfseries\large` for the sectional headings which is different from what is defined in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls). Here are the defaults:

- `\section`: `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`
- `\subsection`: `\normalfont\large\bfseries`
- `\subsubsection`: `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries`
- `\paragraph`: `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries`
- `\subparagraph`: `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries`

`\quad` is the regular skip between the sectional number/counter and title/heading. It is defined as a horizontal skip of `1em`, which is relative to the font size used - a good thing. Finally, if you want a regular rule at the baseline level, use `\hrulefill` instead of `\Vhrulefill`. Of course, any of the other methods described to provide a vertically centered `\hrulefill` should also work.

Comment: Maybe you should add `\unskip` after `#1` to remove spaces at end of `\section{...}`, e.g. because of a line break before closing brace.

Comment: If there are line-breaks in the title text like this: `\section{First\\ section`}, how to solve it?

Comment: @lyl: Try with `\section[First section]{First\\section}`.

Comment: I mean the typeset of this section title become ugly(the title is not centerlined ever) when there are linebreaks in title. So...