# Awesome-CV edit section. make it capital and in center

Tags: templates, cv, fontawesome, awesome-cv

Template for resume used : [Awesome-CV.](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)

I tried for 3 hrs to make all the letters of section capital and set the location of word in vertical center of document. Didn't worked out.

The education.tex is :

```
\cvsection{Education}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
    {B.S. in Computer Science and Engineering}
    {POSTECH(Pohang University of Science and Technology)}
    {Pohang, S.Korea}
    {Mar. 2010 - PRESENT}
    {
      \begin{cvitems}
        \item {Got a Chun Shin-Il Scholarship which is given to promising students in CSE Dept.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
\end{cventries}
```

\cvsection definition:

```
% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{
  %\par\addvspace{1.5ex}
  %\phantomsection{}
    \centering
  \sectionstyle{#1}
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}
}
```

\sectionstyle definition :

```
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{14pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
```

\@sectioncolor definition:

```
% Awesome section color
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\else%
        awesome\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}
```

Attempts include:

[centering attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33386/section-heading-text-embedded-in-horizontal-rule)

`\def\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}` - its not exact. link lost but mentioned by memory what i remembered.

Comment: Please post the actual code. (1) This site is meant to be self-contained so questions and answers don't 'break' simply because another website disappeared or changed its links or .... (2) Not everyone has a ShareLaTeX account or wants to create one (I do not). For what it's worth, `\def\textlcsc[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}` cannot work the way you hope.  And of course, if you're really in a rush (and you don't need to worry about things like headers or tables of contents), you can might be able to type `\section{ALL IN CAPITALS}` (though it depends on how `\section` is defined).

Comment: @jon i have added the sections. let me know if something else is required.

Comment: Unfortunately, code snippets are often not useful when it comes to LaTeX.  Please read about [minimal examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). However, you can try changing the `#1` in  `\sectionstyle` to `\MakeUppercase{#1}`. And it looks like the `\centering` in `\cvsection` is being affected by the `\vhrulefill` (but that looks like a custom command). Of course, it is hard to test if people don't have the `.cls` -- why isn't this on CTAN?

Comment: The fact that the `\fontsize` command is used incorrectly doesn't inspire confidence....

Comment: ShareLaTeX uses a deprecated version of the template. Current one is on github.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the information but right now i have already made many changes so cant move to latest version.

Comment: Below is the solution that worked for me. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\vhrulefill creates a horizontal rule/line. Just make a line before the name entry. i.e \sectionstyle{#1} below.

\cvsection defination:

```
% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{
%\par\addvspace{1.5ex}
%\phantomsection{}
 \centering
\sectionstyle{#1}
\color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
\par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}
}
```

NEW \cvsection defination:

```
% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{
%\par\addvspace{1.5ex}
\color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}         %New addition
%\phantomsection{}
 \centering
\sectionstyle{#1}
\color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
\par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}
}
```

For information, no changes below.

\vhrulefill defination :

```
% Use to draw horizontal line with specific tickness
\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: ronpatelAwesomeSection]

For the current version, available on github:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}
  \hbox{}%
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
  \sectionstyle{#1}
  \phantomsection
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\strut\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\scshape\@sectioncolor #1}}
\makeatother
```

I avoided upper-casing the whole section titles and restricted the output to use small caps.