# Page numbering in the middle of a line

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, tikz-styles

How can I set up a document to write the page numbering in the middle of a line?

Through fancy pagestyle I've got a situation like the following one:

```
--------------------- % this is a line after the body of my document
          1           % this is another line with the page number, centered
```

While I'd like to have a situation such as the following:

```
--------- 1 --------- % this is only a line after the body of my document
```

How can I do that?
A first solution may involve tikz, but is it needed or there are other solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take the `\Vhrulefill` macro for this (posted by Gonzalo Medina in [Vertically centered horizontal rule filling the rest of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/vertically-centered-horizontal-rule-filling-the-rest-of-a-line))

I appended a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\def\Vhrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\fancyfoot{\Vhrulefill~\thepage~\Vhrulefill}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you paste directly the link it will appear immediately the title of the question, which is more clear than `here`. :)

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is based on the following packages:

- [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes)
- [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background)

Basically, by means of `tikzpagenodes` it is possible to access to `current page footer area`:

```
\newcommand{\myfooterstyle}[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
   \draw[#1]
   ($(current page footer area.south west)!0.25!(current page footer area.north west)$)
   --
   ($(current page footer area.south)!0.25!(current page footer area.north)-(#2,0)$)
   ($(current page footer area.south)!0.25!(current page footer area.north)+(#2,0)$)
   --
   ($(current page footer area.south east)!0.25!(current page footer area.north east)$)
   ;
  }%
}
```

The mandatory argument specifies how much distant is the rule from the page number while the optional argument let you access possible customization like colors or rule width. Because of the options `[remember picture, overlay]` two compilation runs are necessary.

Then, by means of the `background` package, the command will be executed everytime:

```
\AddEverypageHook{%
\myfooterstyle{1em}
\BgMaterial}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\newcommand{\myfooterstyle}[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
   \draw[#1]
   ($(current page footer area.south west)!0.25!(current page footer area.north west)$)
   --
   ($(current page footer area.south)!0.25!(current page footer area.north)-(#2,0)$)
   ($(current page footer area.south)!0.25!(current page footer area.north)+(#2,0)$)
   --
   ($(current page footer area.south east)!0.25!(current page footer area.north east)$)
   ;
  }%
}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\myfooterstyle{1em}
\BgMaterial}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

How it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your own style:

```
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}%
    {\hfil\thepage\hfil}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}%
    {\hfil\thepage\hfil}
```

Comment: And the line? It would be more useful for reader you explain what you are doing in your given code, for example the reader may not know `@evenfoot` (how to handle the `@`).

Comment: I've read post inattentive (deciding that "line" is a text line, not a rule). To make a rule just replace \hfil as above. Or even so: `\def\hRfil{\leaders\hbox to 1pt{-}\hfil}`, `\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hRfil\hbox to 2em{\hfil\thepage\hfil}\hRfil}`