# Custom page numbering: large lines between page numbers

Tags: page-numbering

I have to put two large lines between each page number, like this

[image: screenshot]

I am using `MikTeX 2.9` and `WinEDT` and I am on Windows XP.

I have consulted the fancyhdr package documentation, but I couldn't find anything that can help me; or maybe I'm not clever enough.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) I added the image, and removed the thanks- this may seem a bit strange, but we try to keep this site Q&A :) [http://tex.stackexchange.com/about](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) Welcome!

Comment: This question was asked before. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94688/page-numbering-in-the-middle-of-a-line - this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\rule[2pt]{3cm}{2pt}\quad
 \thepage\quad
\rule[2pt]{3cm}{2pt}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Thank you David. But now I have another problem; the lines don't appear on every page. For example, on 6,7 they appear, on 8 no, 9, 10 yes, 11 no, 12-15 yes, 16 no. It's quite irregular. Can it be because it's a report with the option twoside?

Comment: @Catalin -- is it possible that pages 8, 11 and 16 start a chapter, or some other subdivision that incorporates a distinct page style?  (you don't mention what document class you're using, so this may not be relevant.)

Comment: On a closer inspection of my document, I realize you are right; on the pages where the lines don't appear I began a new chapter. Also, after adding your code, I have headers on each page. I've tried using the option \fancyhf{} and \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} to remove it, but then I lose the lines and the numbers.

Comment: @Catalin your chapter pages will be using pagestyle plain or empty so you need to set up the style for those using fanyhdr you shouldn't lose the rule if you do \fancyhf{} _before_ defining your own styles

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. To get the fancy style to work on a chapter page, I had to redefine the plain style, because the first page of a chapter has this style. To remove the header, I simply used \fancyhead{}