# How can I fill a line from the left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I am fiddling with various ways of filling a line with a vertically centered line and experimenting with the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553392/latex-rule-filling-the-line and here: [Vertically centered horizontal rule filling the rest of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/vertically-centered-horizontal-rule-filling-the-rest-of-a-line). Now, I would like the line to fill the beginning (left) of the line - not the rest. It seems "fill" commands do not do anything unless the line contains "something" before the fill part. How can I do this so that I can fill the line with a rule like this:

----------------------------------------------- Text

Where the text is flush right?

Comment: `\leavevmode\null` or `\noindent\null` should do it.

Comment: Great, that does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

What you place before can be empty. The following example is taken from [Vertically centered horizontal rule filling the rest of a line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32597/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill
\newcommand{\xfill}[2][1ex]{{%
  \dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
  \leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill%
}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}\xfill{1pt} Here is some text \par
\mbox{}\xfill{8pt} Here is some text \par
\mbox{}\xhrulefill{blue}{2pt} Here is some text \par
\mbox{}\xhrulefill{cyan}{1ex} Here is some text \par
\mbox{}\xrfill[0ex]{1ex}[red]{} Here is some text \par
\end{document}​
```

`\mbox{}` sets an empty box and initiates a paragraph (similar to what TeX's `\leavevmode` does). Also, to avoid paragraph indentation, I've set `\parindent` to `0pt`. However, you can control this individually using `\noindent`.

Comment: An \mbox seems to take up a little bit of horizontal space, whereas \leavevmode\null suggested by @barbara-beeton does not.
P.S. I avoided the above solution because I was trying to accomplish it with a simple one-liner, not requiring extra packages such as `xhfill`.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: That should not be the case, however, if you feel comfortable with it, `\leavevmode` *only* should do the job. You can also open [`xhfill.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xhfill/xhfill.sty) and use the code in there for horizontal rules (or leaders) in whichever way you want.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: Probably there is a space after `\mbox{...}` before the rule. This space after the curly brace is not ignored in horizontal mode unlike spaces after command names. Technically `\mbox{}` is the same as `\leavevmode\null`, because `\mbox{}` expands to `\leavevmode\hbox{}` and `\null` expands to `\hbox{}`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I had a space after the `\mbox{}`.