# Combine \rule and \fbox to fill the width of a page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules, textwidth

I'm trying to build a date separator, which spans the entire width of the page and has a boxed date on the right. This is what I've written so far:

```
Test test test. 
\par\noindent\hfill\rule[3.4pt]{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\fbox{\texttt{2021-04-08}}
Test test test.
```

And this is the output:
[image]

I'd like to do the following:

- have `\rule` span the entire `\textwidth`, up to the box on the right
- have `\rule` sit at half the height of the box (I guess that's almost done already)
- start a new paragraph after the date (currently it continues in the same line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use This [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/) to define another new command for your work.
Like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\def\Vhrulefill{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth
    \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt%
}
\newcommand{\myDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\Vhrulefill\fbox{\texttt{#1}}\par
}
\begin{document}
Test test test. 
\myDate{2021-04-08}
Test test test. 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm. Thank you!