# In Table, horizontal row with text at some position. I want a horizontal row with word "oder" to fit my table. The position of the row is in image

Tags: tables, text

[image: left-rotated table outlining the intended goal of the asker]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
%\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-4.5cm}{}

\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l}{methods abcdefghikl }  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{r|}{multimedia}\\
 \multicolumn{6}{|l}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{4}{r|}{}\\
\hline

%\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{frsturcio} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{5}{l|}{take the picture}\\
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} &\multicolumn{5}{l|}{}\\
\hline

 & on$-$ & \multicolumn{2}{l}{bench}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{kids} \\[-0.2em]
& dopal$-$ & \multicolumn{2}{l}{last}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{banana}\\
&test$-$ &\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& &7 &5 & 9 &8&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{paradise}\\
1&martin & \multicolumn{2}{l}{omanrtu}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{l|}{kostric}\\ \cline{3-12}
& & \multicolumn{2}{l}{}&&&&&&&&\\
&& \multicolumn{2}{l}{name}&& 8&9 & 10 &25 & 90 & 15 & 20\\
&& \multicolumn{2}{l}{apple}&&&&&&9&8&7\\ \cline{2-12}
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}&&&&&&&\\
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{mk}&15&12&7&4&2&1&0\\
\hline


\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & & &  &  & &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{network} & & 5 & 7 & 6 & 4 &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{3}\\ \cline{2-12}
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & & &  &  & &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\ 
\multirow{2}{*}{}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{jk} &&20&17&13&8&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{3}\\
\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & &  & &  &  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
\multirow{2}{*}{3} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{nylon} & & 8 & 7& 5& 5 &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{4}\\ \cline{2-12}
\multirow{2}{*}{}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
\multirow{2}{*}{}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{pi} &&30&25&20&10&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{5}\\
\hline

&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{poteqa} &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{lno}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{last} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{multicolour}\\
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{fmjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}\\
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{omjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}\\
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}\\
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}\\
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy mjkouy}\\
4 &\multicolumn{3}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\
 &\multicolumn{3}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\
 &\multicolumn{3}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\
 &\multicolumn{3}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{}\\ \cline{2-12}
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{pp}&25&20&12&6&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0}\\
\hline

&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}& \multirow{2}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} \\ 
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}} & \multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}& \multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}}\\
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}& \multirow{2}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{oman}} \\ \cline{3-8} \cline{9-10} \cline{11-12}

&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}} & \multirow{1}{*}{}& \multirow{1}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}\\
5&mjkouy$-$&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}} & \multirow{1}{*}{}& \multirow{1}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}\\
&mjkouy$-$&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{0}} & \multirow{1}{*}{0,0$-$0,2}& \multirow{1}{*}{0,2$-$0,5} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{mjkouy}}\\
&mjkouy&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}} & \multirow{1}{*}{}& \multirow{1}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}\\ \cline{3-12}

&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}\\
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}} & \multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{mjkouy}} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{mjkouy}}\\
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}&  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{mjkouy}} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{mjkouy}}\\ \cline{2-12}

&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}\\
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{I5}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{10}&7&4&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{0}\\
\hline

&\multicolumn{3}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}& \multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy} &\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy} &\multirow{2}{*}{umjkouy} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{mjkouy}}\\
6&\multicolumn{3}{l}{mjkouy}& &\multirow{2}{*}{}& \multirow{2}{*}{} &\multirow{2}{*}{} &\multirow{2}{*}{} &\multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}\\ \cline{2-12}

&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}&&0 &5&8&9&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{5} \\ \cline{3-12}
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
&pp&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}&&0 &2&7&15&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{25} \\ \cline{3-12}
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{}&&&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\
&&\multicolumn{2}{l}{mjkouy}&&0 &5&25&50&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{60} \\ 
\hline


\end{tabular}
%\end{adjustwidth}
%\end{table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately your question is enterally clear. Does this line demarcate rows wot some content or this are actually content of table? It seems, thy you need to draw your table as image.

Comment: The line shown in figure should have word "oder" in some part and is part of table. There are two rows where I want to have such a rows

Comment: Can someone help me with this table?

Comment: @Aqib Please take a look at my answer. I want to know if is in the right track,

Comment: No, there should not be a separate cell for the word "Oder". 
but a horizontal row with word "oder" written at some parts.just as shown in hand drawn table image

Comment: @Aqib I updated the image, with focus in the block #5.

Comment: Can you give me the code

Comment: You want the full table or just the block #5 and you do the rest?

Comment: I would like to have full code.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please test the code and tell me if everything is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this close to what you are looking for? Otherwise, indicate the changes that need to be made, and I will add the code.

This is the final table. Only the packages that are relevant remained.

[image: w]

This is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

% added  <<<<<<<
%%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/vertically-centered-horizontal-rule-filling-the-rest-of-a-line
\newcommand{\Rhrule}{\leavevmode\kern-0.5ex\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern-6pt}
\newcommand{\Lhrule}{\leavevmode\kern-6pt\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0.5ex}
\usepackage{bigstrut} % added  <<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{frsturcio}                                                               &                                                                               \multicolumn{7}{c|}{take the picture} \bigstrut[t]                                                                                \\
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                   &                             &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}     &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}     &           \multicolumn{1}{c}{}           &           \multicolumn{1}{c}{}           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  \bigstrut[b]   \\ \hline
        \multirow{8}[6]{*}{1}  & on-                                    & bench                       &    \multirow{4}[2]{*}{7}    &    \multirow{4}[2]{*}{5}    &          \multirow{4}[2]{*}{9}           &          \multirow{4}[2]{*}{8}           & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{kids} \bigstrut[t]                        \\
                               & dopal-                                 & last                        &                             &                             &                                          &                                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{banana}                                   \\
                               & test-                                  &                             &                             &                             &                                          &                                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{paradise}                                 \\
                               & martin                                 & omanrtu                     &                             &                             &                                          &                                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{kostric} \bigstrut[b]                     \\ \cline{3-10}
                               & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{}                   &                             &    \multirow{3}[2]{*}{8}    &    \multirow{3}[2]{*}{9}    &          \multirow{3}[2]{*}{10}          &          \multirow{3}[2]{*}{25}          &                      &                      &  \bigstrut[t]   \\
                               &                                        & name                        &                             &                             &                                          &                                          &          90          &          15          &       20        \\
                               &                                        & apple                       &                             &                             &                                          &                                          &          9           &          8           & 7 \bigstrut[b]  \\ \cline{2-10}
                               &                       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{mk}                        &             15              &             12              &                    7                     &                    4                     &          2           &          1           &   0 \bigstrut   \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{2}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{network}                                         &              5              &              7              &                    6                     &                    4                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3} \bigstrut                \\ \cline{2-10}
                               &                       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{jk}                        &             20              &             17              &                    13                    &                    8                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{3} \bigstrut                \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}[4]{*}{3}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{nylon}                                           &              8              &              7              &                    5                     &                    5                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{4} \bigstrut                \\ \cline{2-10}
                               &                       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{pi}                        &             30              &             25              &                    20                    &                    10                    &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{5} \bigstrut                \\ \hline
        \multirow{11}[4]{*}{4} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{10}[2]{*}{mjkouy}}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{poteqa} &         \multicolumn{1}{l|}{lno}         &        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{last}         & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{multicolour} \bigstrut[t]                 \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{fmjkouy}       & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}                                   \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{omjkouy}       & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}                                   \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}                                   \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}                                   \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &    \multirow{5}[1]{*}{}     &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy  mjkouy }                          \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &                             &           \multirow{4}[1]{*}{}           &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &           \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{4}[1]{*}{}}           \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                &    \multirow{3}[1]{*}{}     &                             &                                          &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1mjkouy}       &                     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                     \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                &                             &                             &                                          &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &                     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                     \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}                                                &                             &                             &                                          &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        &              \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \bigstrut[b]               \\ \cline{2-10}
                               &                       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{pp}                        &             25              &             20              &                    12                    &                    6                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0} \bigstrut                \\ \hline
        \multirow{11}[4]{*}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{mjkouy}}      &        \multirow{2}[1]{*}{mjkouy}        &        \multirow{2}[1]{*}{mjkouy}        &           \multicolumn{3}{c|}{mjkouy} \bigstrut[t]            \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &                   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &                                          &                                          &                   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{oman}                   \\
                               &                                             \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule}                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule} &           \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule}           \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{0}}         &       \multirow{4}[0]{*}{$0,0-0,2$}        &       \multirow{4}[0]{*}{$0,2-0,5$}        &        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{$>0,5$}}        \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{mjkouy }  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &                   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &                                          &                                          &                     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                     \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{mjkouy -} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &                   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &                                          &                                          &                     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                     \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}|}{mjkouy }  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &                   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &                                          &                                          &                     \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                     \\
                               &                                             \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule}                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule} &           \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\Lhrule oder \Rhrule}           \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy} &      \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{mjkouy}}      &        \multirow{2}[1]{*}{mjkouy}        &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy}                                   \\
                               & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{}                  &                             &                   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                   &                                          &       \multicolumn{1}{l|}{mjkouy}        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{mjkouy} \bigstrut[b]                      \\ \cline{2-10}
                               &                       \multicolumn{2}{c|}{15}                        &                  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{10}                  &                    7                     &                    4                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{0} \bigstrut                \\ \hline
        \multirow{5}[8]{*}{6}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{mjkouy }                                         & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{mjkouy } & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{mjkouy } &       \multirow{2}[2]{*}{mjkouy }        &       \multirow{2}[2]{*}{umjkouy }       & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{mjkouy }} \bigstrut[t] \\
                               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{mjkouy }                                         &                             &                             &                                          &                                          & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{} \bigstrut[b]                            \\ \cline{2-10}
                               & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{pp}                 & mjkouy                      &              0              &              5              &                    8                     &                    9                     &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{5} \bigstrut                \\ \cline{3-10}
                               &                                        & mjkouy                      &              0              &              2              &                    7                     &                    15                    &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{15} \bigstrut               \\ \cline{3-10}
                               &                                        & mjkouy                      &              0              &              5              &                    25                    &                    50                    &               \multicolumn{3}{c|}{60} \bigstrut               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, there should not be a separate cell for the word "Oder". but a horizontal row with word "oder" written at some parts.

Comment: @Aqib You mean without the vertical  borders lines in that row?

Comment: I think now it will be clear from the image

Comment: Yes this is correct 
Can you give me the code?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar to `{tabular}` (of `array`) but constructs PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter` to put whatever Tikz node you want in the tabular.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

 \begin{document}

 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines]
 \Block{5-1}{5}
 & \Block{3-1}{mjkouy\\mjkouy\\mjkouy}
 & \Block{1-1}{mjkouy\\mjkouy}
 & mjkouy & mjkouy & mjkouy & mjkouy \\
 && \Block{1-1}{mjkouy\\mjkouy}
 & 0 & $0.0$-$0.2$ & $0.2$-$0.5$ & $>0.5$ \\
 && mjkouy 
 & mjkouy & mjkouy & mjkouy & mjkouy \\
 \\
 \\
 \CodeAfter 
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x in {2,3} 
        \foreach \y in {4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5}
          { \node [fill=white,yshift=0.35mm] at (\x-|\y) {oder} ; }
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{NiceTabular}

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because PGF/Tikz uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

With the same technique when there is a `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{4}{w{c}{3em}}}[cell-space-limits = 6pt, hvlines]
text    & text      & text  & text  \\
text    & \Block{1-2}{2-cell BLOCK}
                    &       & text  \\
$\frac{\frac{\frac ab}c}d$   & text      & text  & text  \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \node [fill=white,yshift=0.3ex] at (3-|3) {order} ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]