# rule at middle of text hight

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

ich have the following code:

```
    \begin{center}
      \rule{0.2\linewidth}{0.1mm}\hspace{0.5em}
      \textbf{\large Analytische Aufgaben}\hspace{0.5em}
      \rule{0.2\linewidth}{0.1mm}
    \end{center}
```

What i want is that the text ist in between the lines like this: 
|-------------- Analytische Aufgaben ------------| 
The "----" should be on line and fill across the full horizontal page. "|" indicates the ends of the page.

I've tried multiple things but didn't get it workling.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the package `xhfill`, but its documentation is very poor.

Alternatively

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myfillrule}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders
  \hrule height\dimeval{0.5ex+0.2pt} depth \dimeval{-0.5ex+0.2pt}%
  \hfill\hspace*{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\myfillrule\enspace
Analytische Aufgaben\enspace
\myfillrule
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the thickness, replace the two occurrences of `0.2pt` with half the desired dimension.

If you prefer that the rules are vertically centered with respect to uppercase letters, use

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myfillrule}{%
  \leavevmode
  \leaders
  \hrule height\dimeval{0.5\fontcharht\font`A+0.2pt} depth \dimeval{-0.5\fontcharht\font`A+0.2pt}%
  \hfill\hspace*{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\myfillrule\enspace
Analytische Aufgaben\enspace
\myfillrule
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

with the same suggestion as above about the thickness.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i wanted! :)

Answer (score 1):

you could easy define a new centered rule like in the following:

```latex
\documentclass[%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
%showframe % Uncomment this to see the frames of the textbody
]{geometry}

\def\centerrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \centerrulefill\space
    \textbf{\large Analytische Aufgaben}%
    \space\centerrulefill
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Further options are described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32597/vertically-centered-horizontal-rule-filling-the-rest-of-a-line).

But if you want to use this, for example, as a section heading, there are other packages and options.

Comment: Thanks! The link is very helpful.